# FormattedMessage with defaultMessage shows error on console

Tags: reactjs, react-intl

The application I'm working on with has the option to add custom fields for a expecifc form and those fields does not support internationalization. However due to Components on our project, even after adding `defaultMessage` on `FormattedMessage`, we're receiving the following error:

```
[React Intl] Missing message: "Custom Field #01" for locale: "en", using default message as fallback.
```

Here's how our BaseInput was implemented.

```
class BaseInput extends Component {
  render() {
    let { id, style, label, required, errorMessage } = this.props;
    let errorClass = errorMessage ? "text-field-error" : "";

    return (
      <div className={errorClass} style={style}>
        <label
          id={`${id}_label`}
          name={`${id}_label`}
          className="ui-outputlabel"
        >
          <FormattedMessage id={label} defaultMessage={label} />
        </label>
        {required && <span className="wms-required-field"> *</span>}
        {this.generateInput()}
        {errorMessage && (
          <div className={"ui-message-error ui-widget ui-corner-all"}>
            <span id={`${id}_error`} className={"ui-message-error-detail"}>
              <FormattedMessage id={errorMessage} />
            </span>
          </div>
        )}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

I know the json doesn't have the translation for the given id. The problem I'm having is the error message on console even when adding the defaultMessage. Does anyone have any suggestion on how to resolve this problem?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you show us the JSON containing your strings ?

Comment: The JSON doesn't contain the id.

Custom field is a field added by other user containing the field's label and input type. Since the custom field is something added on production phase, the system is supose to use the label as a literal value.

Answer (score 0):

You can prevent missing messages from appearing as errors in the console by implementing the `onError` handler of the provider. This will override the default behavior of writing to the console. You can choose to swallow the error.

```
<IntlProvider locale={locale} messages={messages} onError={handleTranslationError}>
  ...
</IntlProvider>
```

Handler

```
const handleTranslationError = err => {
  // swallow error
};
```

Answer (score -1):

This is because you json doesn't have translation for the `id` given in the prop. Only the translations defined and provided in `IntlProvider` can be translated or default message will be shown.

Comment: I know the json doesn't have the translation for the given id. The problem I'm having is the error message on console even when adding the defaultMessage.